# Android: Calendar not returning values?

Tags: android, calendar

I'm trying to run this little code to return a eight-digit `integer` to be used in a `for-loop` later on as a search function. Problem is that it doesn't return any values for `searchDateToday`.  Am I missing something?

```
final Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");
DateToday = formatter.format(cal.getTime()); // YYYYMMDD form -
                                             // Example: 20111010
                                             // = October 10,
                                             // 2011

int searchDateToday = Integer.parseInt(DateToday);
```

Comment: Did you print `DateToday`? Is some exception being thrown?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to use the Date object:

```
final Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");
DateToday = formatter.format(new Date(cal.getTime())); 

// YYYYMMDD form -// Example: 20111010 // = October 10, // 2011

int searchDateToday = Integer.parseInt(DateToday);
```

Comment: This wasn't the problem. I made a real dumb-dumb move completely irrelevant to this. My code still worked. Thanks for your prompt response though.

Comment: Okay, no probz mate. But I'm almost 100% sure you need the Date object, otherwise it wont work! Now you know next time your doing this again :)

Answer (score 0):

use this for getting today date

```
String currentDate = DateFormat.getDateInstance().format(new Date());
tv_date.setText(currentDate);   // tv_date is TextView
```